What is the standard international practice about border fencing?
I have observed that whenever a country wants to fence its border, someone either protests or one side starts firing on the construction workers.
Examples,

Afghan Taliban stop Pakistan army from fencing international border

Lithualia built fence; Belarus damaged it




What is the standard international practice about border fencing?

"I have observed that whenever a country wants to fence its border, the opposite country either protests or starts firing on the construction workers." Selection bias? If a border fences its border and its neighbour does not protest/fires at them, it will probably not be so prominent in the press. And even if you read about it, you are more likely to forget it. Also, how many of those "firing neighbours" are claiming that the land being fenced out is theirs (which would make the incident not only about the fence building but about a boundary dispute).

Could you give us some examples of when a country has fired on the workers of another country constructing border fences? Not Korea, since they are technically at war and are a special case.

I agree with the comment by SJuan regarding reporting bias. Peaceful fencing does not get reported as much. That being said, there are several possibilities:

The border is disputed, and the fence is trying to create facts on the ground. That would be a prime example of actually shooting at workers.
By contrast, look at how Germany and the Netherlands are handling their centuries-old border dispute in the Ems estuary. They more or less decided that the problem cannot be resolved and does not need to be resolved now, and to sign treaties on all practical aspects of the management of the area -- without prejudicing the border question.
There are refugee movements in the area, possibly facilitated by one country to destabilize the other, and neither country wants the refugees to stay on their side of the border.
Look at how the UK is complaining about insufficient fences and similar measures on the French side of the border. The UK does not want any refugees to reach their shores, so they want France to build more fences e.g. at the Channel Tunnel.
By contrast, Russia and Belarus are encouraging the transfer of refugees to the EU, and they complain when the EU raises fences.


Fencing also disrupts animal movements. https://www.dw.com/en/buildout-of-immigration-fences-in-europe-endangers-wildlife/a-19362822 And even politically it's not as uncontroversial as you make it to be. The EU was opposed to Hungary fencing their borders for instance, or at least paying for it. And now to Greece doing the same https://www.euractiv.com/section/politics/news/eu-opposes-funding-fences-as-athens-fears-migration-waves-from-middle-east/

@264champagnebottlesonice, I don't recall EU forces shooting at Hungarian fence-builders. But refugees are an incredibly emotional topic, and a lot of people want them to be housed humanely in some other country ...

"I don't recall EU forces shooting at Hungarian fence-builders". True but the fence was in the press a lot nonetheless. Also, the way you wrote your answer leads one to believe that only Russia or Belarus could possibly oppose fences.

@o.m. The question specifies "someone either protests or one side starts firing". So the EU objecting to Hungary building border walls is still an example.

@F1Krazy, look at the question, and similar questions from the OP. The question strongly implies that violent border conflicts are normal. They are not.
